# FLask-SQLAlchemy checking for duplicates in database

Tags: python, scrapy, flask-sqlalchemy, scrapy-pipeline

Hi I am using the python scrape library to create spiders and extract data from websites. In my pipeline I use Flask-SQLAlchemy to configure the spider so that it adds the scraped data to a SQLite table. I am trying to figure out how to prevent the spider from adding duplicate data to the table so I query the database to see if table already contains an element that is the same as the element that the spider is about to add to the table. If so, I do not want the spider to add the data but simply move on to the next element. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import os
import sys

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime, union
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

app = Flask(__name__)

# Flask-SQLAlchemy
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite://draft.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def db_connect():
    return create_engine('sqlite:///draft.db')

Base = declarative_base()

class Events(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    location = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    date = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    url = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///draft.db')

def create_events_table(engine): 
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class GeneralPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)    

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        event = Events(**item)

        duplicates = union(session.query(Events).filter_by(title=item["title"]), session.query(Events).filter_by(date=item["date"]))

        if duplicates:
            session.close()

        else:
            try:
                session.add(event)
                session.commit()
            except:
                session.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                session.close()

        return item
```

This returns the error  raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined") which I assume refers to the if duplicates: statement however I'm not sure why this would not work. I just want to check if any duplicates exist and if so, the spider should not add that data element to the table. Any pointers on how to make this system work?

Here is more of the stack trace as requested:

```
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
2016-12-06 21:02:34 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'location': None, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 21, 21, 0), 'url': 'http://www.trumba.com/events-calendar/ma/boston/harvard-events/harvard-event-calendar/harvard-activities/gazette', 'title': 'Varsity Show'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 649, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/project/draft/draft/draft/pipelines.py", line 58, in process_item
    if duplicates:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 481, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
2016-12-06 21:02:34 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-12-06 21:02:34 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 524,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 352524,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 7, 2, 2, 34, 379384),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 201,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 7, 2, 2, 32, 3552)}
2016-12-06 21:02:34 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Can you post more of your stack trace?

Comment: stack trace has been posted -- I didn't post all of it because the TypeError repeats for every element the spider tries to scrape

Comment: Apparently `sqlalchemy.union(session.query(...), session.query(...))` cannot be evaluated as a boolean. Don't you need to execute the query? (btw, I'm ignorant in `sqlalchemy`)